# postfix send mail through another smtp server?

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix, webmin

im running debian squeeze virtualmin/webmin vps with postfix in australia

my main email account is through a company in america

i want to be able to send email to my aus vps smtp server, and then have it pass it on to my account at my usa email provider

i want this as its alot quicker

(i tried adding a user to my vps, which lets me send emails, but they are marked as spoofed due to not actually having been sent by the domain that the email address is of)

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to be able to send email to my aus vps smtp server, and then have it pass it on to my account at my usa email provider

In Postfix, configure the **`relayhost`** option:

`relayhost = [other.server]`

> but they are marked as spoofed due to not actually having been sent by the domain that the email address is of

This can be configured in the domain's SPF records.

Comment: but will this send all emails that way, how can i make it only pass on emails for the one user ?

Comment: would i do it with this ? : sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

Comment: yes it appears so, i will mark this as answered, though im still to work out exactly how to do it...